# What actually is uniform convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, even-and-odd-functions

I am calculating the Fourier series of odd and even extensions of various functions e.g. $cos(x),x^2,e^x$ etc.

I need to **state** whether each series converges uniformly or not, I am struggling to grasp what actually does uniform convergence mean without having to prove it rigorously.

For example I found that the Fourier series for an odd extension of $cos(x)$ over $[-\pi,\pi]$ to be the infinite sum:

$f_1(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}[\frac{4}{3}sin(2x)+\frac{8}{15}sin(4x) + ...+\frac{2*(2k)}{(2k)^2-1}sin(2kx)+...]$

How would I immediately know or be able to check whether this series converges uniformly?

Comment: uniform convergence is equivalent to convergence using the supremum norm.

Comment: Uniform convergence means that you have a uniform control over the speed of convergence of $f_n(x)$ as $n\to\infty$ for different values of $x$'s.

Comment: One way to check is: if a series of continuous functions uniformly converges to a function, that limit will be continuous. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem). Thus (contrapositive): if the function you are making the Fourier series for is not continuous, the convergence cannot be uniform.

Comment: @StinkingBishop are there certain values of $x$ that I can take for which the convergence would be uniform for a non-continuous function?

Comment: There is no such thing as uniform convergence at the point. Uniform convergence is all about the values converging *at all points* at (so to speak) similar speeds - i.e. for large enough $n$, the partial sums are $\varepsilon$-close to the total sum at *all points*.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Is it possible for convergence to be uniform on an interval of $x$ for a non-continuous function?

Comment: @StinkingBishop Nevermind, I realised that you have uniform convergence everywhere except at points of discontinuity